# "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Losing my mind here, trying to figure this one out. Here is the SQL:

```
Update `ScheduledShifts` ss 
LEFT JOIN `Shifts` s ON ss.`ShiftID` == s.`ShiftID` 
SET ss.`IsWeekend` 
WHERE (s.`WeekendDays` & (1 << (DAYOFWEEK(ss.`OriginalShiftDate`)-1))) <> 0;
```

and the full error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== s.`ShiftID` SET ss.`IsWeekend` WHERE (s.`WeekendDays` & (1 << (DAYOFWEEK(ss.`' at line 1

Comment: MySQL's equality operator is `=`, not `==`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update ScheduledShifts ss LEFT JOIN Shifts s ON ss.ShiftID = s.ShiftID SET ss.IsWeekend WHERE (s.WeekendDays & (1 << (DAYOFWEEK(ss.OriginalShiftDate)-1))) <> 0;
```

*Short answer: Single equals, not double equals sign in your query!*

I have never performed an update with left join in a single query before so I don't know if that is an issue in itself but do believe your double equals sign is the problem.

In scripting languages, your == would be valid, but within an sql request, its illegal.

Comment: Thanks, this did it. Can't believe I wasted so much time on a single character. ah!

`UPDATE ScheduledShifts ss
LEFT JOIN Shifts s ON ss.ShiftID = s.ShiftID
SET ss.IsWeekend = 1 
WHERE (s.WeekendDays & (1 << (DAYOFWEEK(ss.OriginalShiftDate)-1))) <> 0;
`

Comment: Educate me: *UPDATE ScheduledShifts ss LEFT JOIN Shifts s* What is ss and s in this context? A table or a column within a table? Which table? I have never seen two values follow an UPDATE or a LEFT JOIN so you got me curious.

Comment: @fiprojects `s` and `ss` are [table aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: Thanks Dezza - I will go research more into this.

Answer (score 1):

The error is itself answering. Use `=` instead of `==`.

```
UPDATE ScheduledShifts ss 
LEFT JOIN Shifts s ON ss.ShiftID = s.ShiftID 
SET ss.IsWeekend 
WHERE (s.WeekendDays & (1 << (DAYOFWEEK(ss.OriginalShiftDate)-1))) <> 0;
```

---

**UPDATE:**

As **@Dezza** said your query is incomplete as your are not settings the column `ss.IsWeekend` to anything.

Comment: Thanks, but still gives:

>  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (s.WeekendDays & (1 << (DAYOFWEEK(ss.OriginalShiftDate)-1))) <> 0' at line 3

Comment: `SET ss.IsWeekend` to what?

Comment: Why the logic change in the edit from bitwise and `&` to logical and `AND`?